# Using variable in date_modify

Tags: php

```
<?php
$universe = $_SESSION["company"];
$universeTimeQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT gameTime FROM universes WHERE Name = :name");
$universeTimeQuery->bindParam(":name", $universe);
$universeTimeQuery->execute();
$universeTime = $universeTimeQuery->fetchColumn();
$foundDate = date('d M Y H:i');
$date = date_create($foundDate);
date_modify($date, '.+$universeTime.' Year');
?>
```

How would I go about making it so that the date_modify function, instead of needing to use +1000 Year, can instead use the number from $universeTime Year? Thank you!

Comment: First you add `session_start();` on top of your PHP code.

Comment: It's a required file, and in the required file there is `session_start();`

Comment: and where are you using the `require()` ? I don't see it anywhere O.o . Atleast mention on your question such that the code you pasted is just an exerpt of your full code.

Comment: No, the file **is** required in another file, and in the other file there is `session_start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add 1000+ years onto the current date.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1000 year');
echo $date->format('d M Y H:i'); ?>
```

You can then just use the data fetched from the MySQL table, instead of using a static value.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+'.$universeTime.' year');
echo $date->format('d M Y H:i'); ?>
```

Comment: Same error, again. `Warning: DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (+ year) at position 0 (+): Unexpected character in /home/sgamex12/public_html/logged.php on line 8`

Comment: What exactly is in $universeTime ? I thought its just an Integer value like 1000. But maybe cast it as an Integer. Try $date->modify('+'.intval($universeTime).' year');

Comment: Maybe also double check that the data is getting retrieved from the database correctly. I think it might just be an empty string by the looks of that error.

Comment: It is an integer in the database.

Comment: echo the data above it using echo var_export($universeTime) and double check the contents. I've tested my code, and it seems to be fine using a variable.

Comment: I realised it was my mistake after all. Thank you for the help!